# « en » : qu'est-ce qu'il fait dans cette phrase

Tags: sens, en

> Le verdict en était assurément un qu'une juge ... aurait pu raisonnablement rendre.

Il semble que le mot « en » ne change pas le sens de cette phrase. Est-elle correcte même si on omet « en » ?

Answer (score 4):

Mon avis diffère légèrement de celui de jlliagre. Pour moi, la phrase n'est pas correcte si on omet le "en" (donc la réponse à la question est **non**) :

> Le verdict était assurément un qu'une juge aurait pu rendre

Le "*en*" ici fait référence au mot **verdict**. On peut effectivement le remplacer comme l'a dit jlliagre, mais pas simplement le supprimer :

> Le verdict était assurément un [**verdict** / **de ceux**] qu'une juge aurait pu rendre

Le caractère idiomatique de ces tournures est également subjectif.
Personnellement je trouve la tournure "**en était un**" plus "*pompeuse*", mais finalement pas particulièrement déplacée compte tenu du contexte administratif de la phrase.

Une autre tournure pourrait également être (de manière plus directe) :

> C'était assurément un verdict qu'une juge aurait pu rendre

Comment: Ah, mon *oui* était un contresens par rapport à ce que je voulais dire. Je l'ai supprimé et clarifié ma réponse.

Answer (score 0):

Ce ***en*** semble de trop. Il ne correspond à rien de la phrase originale qui a été rédigée en anglais :

> *The verdict was clearly **one** that a properly instructed judge acting judicially, could reasonably have rendered.*

Sa traduction française est un peu bizarre :

> Le verdict **en** était assurément **un** qu’une juge qui a reçu les directives appropriées et qui agit d’une manière judiciaire aurait pu raisonnablement rendre.

Mon opinion est que la phrase n'est pas idiomatique avec ce **en** mais ne vaut pas mieux sans ce dernier. Le traducteur a probablement commencé par écrire :

> Le verdict était assurément un qu'une juge

puis s'est rendu compte que ça ne passait pas en français et a ajouté **en** car la forme :

> Le verdict en était assurément un

existe bien. Le problème est qu'elle ne signifie pas tout à fait la même chose que *The verdict was clearly one (that a judge...)* et que le **un** doit être le dernier mot de ce type de phrase. On pourrait la traduire par *The verdict was really a verdict*.

Une tournure plus naturelle et conforme au document original, ce qui est particulièrement indiqué pour un texte juridique, retirerait ce **en** et modifierait ***un*** pour donner :

> Le verdict était assurément **un de ceux**<sup>1</sup> qu’une juge qui a reçu les directives appropriées et qui agit d’une manière judiciaire aurait pu raisonnablement rendre.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Ou ...**celui** qu'une juge...</sub>